# jQuery loading screen into pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I have this loading screen script that I'd like to implement into a project.

However it requires jQuery. And since none of the elements in the page need jQuery, I'd like to save some space and avoid adding it.

Is there any way I can deliver the exact same function with pure JavaScript?

**HTML:**

```
<body onload="hide_preloader();">    
<div class="preloader"> <div class="loader"></div> </div>
</body>
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(window).load(function() { rotate = 0; $(".preloader").fadeOut(250); });
```

Thanks

Comment: jQuery source code is searchable, see how it implements `fadeOut()`.

Comment: Since jQuery *is* pure JavaScript: Yes.

Comment: If you use jQuery in your other pages, then it is false economy to avoid it in one page, since it will be cached after the first request anyway. And if you use a CDN like Google it will likely already be cached. You are making your application more complex by avoiding jQuery in one page, and using time likely better spent elsewhere.

Comment: If you load jQuery [from the Google CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery), chances are the user's browser already has it cached so it really doesn't cost much!! If not, for a simple solution consider setting the CSS opacity with Javascript (remember to compensate for MSIE if necessary), then [CSS3 transitions](http://bavotasan.com/2011/a-simple-fade-with-css3/) in your stylesheet to make it animate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is actually surprisingly easy. You can do the fade with CSS transitions instead.

First, let's define some CSS:

```
.preloader {
    transition: opacity 0.25s linear; /* when we change the opacity, use these transition settings */
}

.preloader.fade {
    opacity: 0;  /* when we add the class fade, set the opacity to 0 using the above transition */
}
```

Now we simply have to add the `fade` class with Javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var preloader = document.getElementsByClassName('preloader')[0];

    preloader.className += ' fade';

    setTimeout(function(){
        preloader.style.display = 'none';
    }, 300);
};
```

Browsers that don't understand `transition` will set `opacity` to `0` immediately, while as an absolute failsafe (e.g. for browsers that don't understand `opacity`) we set `display` to `none` after a second for everyone.

[jsFiddle showing this effect](http://jsfiddle.net/lonesomeday/G247Q/3/). (Obviously you will style `.preloader` differently.)

Comment: Will I be able to access the content below?

Comment: @Boris As you can see [if I pause the animation](http://jsfiddle.net/lonesomeday/G247Q/1/), you can interact with elements that have less than full opacity. Obviously this is also true of `opacity: 0` and `display: none`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @Boris Sorry, I was wrong. Elements with `opacity: 0` prevent access to the content below. You should shorten the timeout to, say, `300`, as I have in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
// taken from http://stackoverflow.com/q/13733912/2332336
function fade(element) {
    var op = 1;  // initial opacity
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        if (op <= 0.1){
            clearInterval(timer);
            element.style.display = 'none';
        }
        element.style.opacity = op;
        element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
        op -= op * 0.1;
    }, 50);
}
```

and this html:

```
<body onload="fade(document.getElementById('preloader'));">  
    <div id="preloader"> <div class="loader"></div> </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var preloader = document.querySelector('.preloader');

  var startTime = new Date().getTime();
  function fadeOut(){
    var passedTime = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
    var opacity = Math.max(250 / (250 - passedTime), 0);
    preloader.style.opacity = opacity;
    if(opacity){
      setTimeout(fadeOut, 0);
    }
  }
  setTimeout(fadeOut, 0);
}
```

Comment: Why not just add a class that has a transition on it?  Isn't this overkill?

Comment: You can't exactly access the content below. I have a `z-index` set to `10`.