# Fade Out 1 Div After 5 Secs and Fade in Another

Tags: javascript, html, zepto

I'm trying to fade out `#one` and then fade in `#two` after 5 seconds.  I'm trying to keep the file as small as possible so would rather not use a library as heavy as jquery since this will only be displayed on mobile devices.

```
<div id="one">div one</div>
<div id="two">div two</div>
```

Comment: So what is the question? Which animation library to use? I would use TweenLite https://greensock.com/

Comment: @Joe if you are looking out not to use jquery, then at least did you try looking into their source code how its implemented? You can just pick up that piece of code

Comment: Are you using modern browsers? Are css transitions an option?

Comment: @LearningNeverStops I wouldn't know how to pick out the specific piece of code

Comment: @EvilBuck this is for mobile phones but i need this to be in javascript instead of css

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript fade in fade out without Jquery and CSS3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733912/javascript-fade-in-fade-out-without-jquery-and-css3)

Comment: @LearningNeverStops how is this a duplicate. what that user asked is not what im looking for

Comment: @JoeBobby What that user asked is without using Jquery get a fadein and fadeout. Now, if you see the code properly, you can at least judge how to add your specific delay. At least try something from there, if you are not able to get the thing working, then makes sense of we helping. :)

Comment: @JoeBobby here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733912/javascript-fade-in-fade-out-without-jquery-and-css3#answer-20533102

Comment: As example - http://jsfiddle.net/qjhjbu6p/ Does not set display to `none`, but easily modifiable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the GSAP library, which performs better than jQuery, even on most mobiles.

**Include GSAP**

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.14.1/TimelineLite.min.js
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="one">div one</div>
<div id="two">div two</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
window.onload = function(){
var greenbox = document.getElementById("one");
var bluebox = document.getElementById("two");
var tl = new TimelineLite();
    /* Fading in and out */
    tl.to(one, 2, {autoAlpha:0, ease:Power1.easeInOut})
    tl.to(two, 2, {autoAlpha:1, ease:Power1.easeInOut}, "-=0.5");
}
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qkds4c2d/ - You can do styles and positioning with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="one" class="animated">div one</div>
<div id="two" class="animated hidden">div two</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("one").className = "animated fadeOut";
document.getElementById("two").className = "animated fadeIn";
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

// https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/blob/master/source/_base.css

.animated {
  animation-duration: 5s; // 1s from source
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

// https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/blob/master/source/fading_entrances/fadeIn.css

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}

.fadeIn {
  animation-name: fadeIn;
}

// https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/blob/master/source/fading_exits/fadeOut.css

@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {opacity: 1;}
  100% {opacity: 0;}
}

.fadeOut {
  animation-name: fadeOut;
}
```