# How to fadeIn and fadeOut an image using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

I am creating an image slider in JavaScript and i want to add effects like fadeIn and fadeOut without jQuery.

html:

```
<body>
<img src="images/1.jpg" alt=""  id="slide" width="700px" height="340px" > 
 </body>
```

JavaScript:

```
var slideshow = new Array();

slideshow[0] = new Image();
slideshow[0].src= "images/1.jpg";

slideshow[1] = new Image();
slideshow[1].src= "images/2.jpg";

slideshow[2] = new Image();
slideshow[2].src= "images/3.jpg";


var inc = 0;

function slide(){
document.getElementById('slide').src = slideshow[inc].src;
if(inc<2)
inc++;
else
inc = 0;
setTimeout("slide()",2000);
}
slide();
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use jquery?

Comment: How do you feel about css? (css3)

Comment: Have you looked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733912/javascript-fade-in-fade-out-without-jquery-and-css3 or here: http://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/cMp7s/

Comment: If i use css animation then it will not work in some browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with Javascript alone because CSS controls opacity for fading. But there is your clue. Use javascript to control the opacity of the image since, in your comment, you said you don't want to use CSS animation properties and opacity should work in every browser.