# How to remove a div with fade out effect in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, fade

I want to remove a div element on click event but i want to remove it with a fade out effect. I have got some JQuery solution but i need pure JavaScript or css solution.

```
document.querySelector('.list').addEventListener("click", function(e){
    if (e.target.localName === "span") {
        var removeTarget = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
        removeTarget.parentNode.removeChild(removeTarget);
    };
});
```

This code is removing the div element with no effect. How can i add a fade out effect?

Comment: jquery is pure javascript.

Comment: I am working on a small project and i don't want to use any frameworks like JQuery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript fade in fade out without Jquery and CSS3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733912/javascript-fade-in-fade-out-without-jquery-and-css3) and a host of others found by searching SO.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are two ways you can achieve this: CSS3 animation or jQuery animation.

### CSS3 Animation

1. In your CSS document, add:

   ```
   .list {
       opacity: 1;
       -webkit-transition: opacity 1000ms linear;
       transition: opacity 1000ms linear;
   }
   ```

   - This will make any change of opacity to your item fade by 1000ms.
2. Change line 4 of your JavaScript to:

   ```
   removeTarget.style.opacity = '0';
   setTimeout(() => removeTarget.remove(), 1000);
   ```

   - This will make your item change opacity to 0, thus making the transition from step 1 have an effect.  Then it will remove the item with your code after 1000ms.

**Note:** Make sure the time of the CSS3 transition and the setTimeout are the same.

### jQuery Animation

1. Get jQuery

   - Go to the [jQuery Website](https://jquery.com/) and download it, or
   - Add ` in your HTML document before any jQuery code.
2. Change line 4 of your Javascript to:

   ```
   removeTarget.fadeOut(1000)
   ```

   - This will Fade Out your item by 1000ms, you can change this time to whatever you want.

Comment: @PariShKhAn Glad I could help, to mark that this worked and for future reference you can press the check mark button toward the top left of my post to accept it.

Comment: very practical although the fixed dependency to the css might be painful at some point later on (1 upvote only :-) )

Comment: Update from 2022: Now you can use `removeTarget.remove();`. No need to access parent and remove child. :-)

Comment: @vee I wish I realized this was a function a few months ago! I just updated my answer to use this

Answer (score 39):

I've made this function a while ago for a personal project:

```
function removeFadeOut( el, speed ) {
    var seconds = speed/1000;
    el.style.transition = "opacity "+seconds+"s ease";

    el.style.opacity = 0;
    setTimeout(function() {
        el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    }, speed);
}

removeFadeOut(document.getElementById('test'), 2000);
```

Comment: Great solution! By the way you don't actually need to calculate the seconds you can use `ms` in transition.

Comment: @pheianox Although your edit on the answer improved clarity & simplicity of the code, it is better to [leave a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) instead of changing an answer (BTW: see the question in ms `1000`, the function-call in answer is in ms `2000`.

Comment: Is there a way to fade in?

Comment: thats a damn sexy solution, works just great except you need to convert from jquery to native js bcs i use jquery for everything else

Comment: @Halo pretty sure you can just have the opacity set to 0 and make it ease in and then set the value permanently, shouldnt be too difficult if you really need it

Answer (score 9):

In 2020 you can forgo use of use `setTimeout` for [the `animationend` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event), removing the need to maintain the duration in two places:

```
.fade-out {
  animation: fade 2s;
  -webkit-animation: fade 2s;
  -moz-animation: fade 2s;
}

/* Animate opacity */
@keyframes fade {
  from { opacity: 1 }
  to { opacity: 0 }
}
@-moz-keyframes fade {
  from { opacity: 1 }
  to { opacity: 0 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from { opacity: 1 }
  to { opacity: 0 }
}

const elementToFade = document.getElementById('my-element');

elementToFade.onanimationend = (e) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('fade-out')) {
    elementToFade.parentNode.removeChild(elementToFade);
  }
};

// To fade away:
elementToFade.classList.add('fade-out');
```

Comment: `event.srcElement` is deprecated now; `event.target` is the recommended property.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good question, but to animate some element in html, this element has to exist while it is animating. So, you have some ways to do this, a good way is hide this element with CSS and after the animation you remove this element. While you hiding you can animate, you can see this example:

```html
<style>
  .hide{
    opacity: 0; 
   }
  .fade-out {
    transition:1s linear all;
  }
</style>
<span class="list fade-out">

  This is a List, click me to hide

</span>

<script>
  document.querySelector('.list').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    
    if (e.target.localName === "span") {
      
      //Add CSS hide and animate with fade out
      var currentCSS = this.className;
      this.className = currentCSS + ' hide';
      
      var removeTarget = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
      setTimeout(function(){
        removeTarget.parentNode.removeChild(removeTarget);
        },1000);
    };
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS class to the element using elem.className="my-animation"; on click:

```
.my-animation {
  animation: fade 3s steps(90) forwards;
 -webkit-animation: fade 3s steps(90) forwards;
  -moz-animation: fade 3s steps(90) forwards;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
}
```

You may control the speed of the animation by modifying the steps(number) as well.

Comment: This will not remove the element from DOM, but that is requested in the question.

Answer (score -3):

Just goto [jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery) source code, take out the `fade` code which is in pure javascript, and use it, no need to reinvent the wheel,

or a hint is reduce the height of div to 0 slowly using `setTimeInterval()`

or a css solution would be to use `transform` and `transition` properties