# Reliable way to fade in new element

Tags: javascript, css, fadein

In my app, I create a new element every second. They should be faded in as they are created. Here's how I did it:

```
window.setInterval(() => {
    const element = document.createElement('div');
    element.classList.add('dot', 'hidden');
    document.getElementById('content').appendChild(element);
    element.classList.remove('hidden');
}, 1000);
```

```css
.dot {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
    margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

I thought this would make the transition work, but it doesn't. I also tried to remove the `hidden` class after a delay, like this:

```
setTimeout(() => element.classList.remove('hidden'), 100);
```

It's interesting, because it works only if the delay is long enough. If I set it to 10 ms, some dots are faded in and other appear instantly.

Is there a better, simple and reliable way to make it work, without guessing the delay of `setTimeout()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733912/javascript-fade-in-fade-out-without-jquery-and-css3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) and avoid using JavaScript if it's a simple fade-in you want. This will only run when the DOM node is painted to the screen. If you need more advanced control over your animations then you can tap into JS.

```
@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.dot {
   display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
    margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
    animation: 1s linear fadein;
 }
```

Comment: Yeah, I think CSS animations are better than transitions when we want to run them instantly. Do you agree?

Comment: @RoboRobok yes, I think animations is the way to go. You can then just insert the element and the animations will kick in. You can still do it using transitions (check my answer) but it requires a lot of JS which is less preferable in general to a pure CSS solution

Answer (score 0):

Your original problem makes sense because you are adding the hidden class and removing it inside the same function in your `setTimeout` block. Remember that the browser gets a chance to rerender only after your function completes executing. This means in the line where you add your `hidden` class is not useful at all because it is immediately removed later in the function (before the browser can do a render).

I would recommend inserting your DOM element and resetting it using a `setTimeout` or `requestAnimationFrame`. Also because the timing of `setInterval` and `setTimeout` are not fully dependable, it may make sense to use the use the `transitionend` event of one element to trigger the addition of the next.

```js
(function() {
  const container = document.getElementById('container');
  let count = 0;

  function addElement() {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = 'item ' + ++count
    container.append(div);
    div.classList.add('item')
    div.addEventListener('transitionend', addElement)
    setTimeout(function() {
      div.classList.add('show')
    }, 0)
  }

  addElement()

})()
```

```css
div {}

div.item {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

div.item.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<hr>

<div id="container">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Css `transition` works best when you hide things.

So here is a solution using javascript only.

```js
window.setInterval(() => {
    const element = document.createElement('div');
    element.classList.add('dot');
    document.getElementById('content').appendChild(element);
    fade(element,0.1);
}, 1000);

// This will inc opacity by 0.1 each 100ms 
function fade(item, i){
i += 0.1;
item.style.opacity = i;
if (i< 1)
setTimeout(()=> fade(item,i), 100);
}
```

```css
.dot {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
    margin: 0 5px 0px 5px;
}



#content {
background:black;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: I used to do it JS way back then in jQuery times, but it's not the most convenient nor efficient way these days, is it?

Comment: Well it depends, for me using js instead of css is always better, so i dont care about the webbrowser etc. And using a library like Jq is even better.

Comment: It's the opposite to me, I always prefer to use CSS whenever possible.